# why doesn't my printf function return the correct scanned value in the following C code?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I want to scan a value, and print the value that was scanned

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("enter value: ");
    n = scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

however, the printed result gave me 1 instead of 9 as shown below. Why is this so and how do i solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `n` get override by the return value of scanf

Just use `scanf("%d", &n);` if you don't want the number of parsed items assigned to `n`.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` does not return the value which it scans, it returns the number of items successfully read. The input `&n` is the address to your buffer which `scanf()` fills in with what it scanned.

Just call

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

if you don't want any error checking.

Answer (score 2):

> why doesn't my printf function return the correct scanned value in the
> following C code?

You are mistaken. The `printf` call

```
n = scanf("%d",&n);
printf("%d",n);
```

outputs the correct value returned by the call of scanf.

According to the (7.21.6.4 The scanf function)

> 3 The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input
> failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed.
> **Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items assigned,** which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the
> event of an early matching failure.

As this call of scanf

```
n = scanf("%d",&n);
```

assigned only one item then its return value is equal to 1. This value you outputted in the next call of printf

```
printf("%d",n);
```

If you want to output the assigned item in the call of scanf then do not overwrite it with the return value of the scanf call as for example

```
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("%d",n);
```

Or you could write

```
if ( scanf("%d",&n) == 1 ) printf("%d",n);
```